# Facing Issue with debugging GA4 for an e-commerce website

Tags: google-analytics-4

I was trying to create a checkout funnel report for an e-comm website in the explore funnel template but there after the minute I was adding the payment step, there was no data coming in for that and the next steps.

But a checkout funnel without the payment step is showing data uptil the purchases made. I'm not sure how to debug this this to check where the issue is, or if I am missing something.

This is the step I am following to setup the checkout funnel in explore:

(event - add_to_cart) is indirectly followed by (event -> checkout) is indirectly followed by (event -> shipping_info) is indirectly follwoed by (payment_info) is indirectly followed by (event -> purchase)

My manager suggested I use debug extension to check if the event is firing but I don't know how to do it without the debugView option in GA4

Comment: In the events report, you could see if any payment_info events are fired.